# Can't extract the data out of the tuple while using the get data eikon package with the refinitiv API

Tags: python, tuples

```
# Use the Data Item Browser to find the name of the TR
## Manually calculate the PE

   test = ek.get_data(['IBM','AAPL.O'],['TR.DPSmean','TR.PriceClose'])
   test
```

OUTPUT

```
  Out[36]: 
  (  Instrument  Dividend Per Share - Mean  Price Close
 0        IBM                      6.675       140.88
 1     AAPL.O                    0.97507       132.23,
 None)
```

Here is where I retrieve the infos. What I want to do is just simply divide the Price close by the dividend per share But every time I get a tuple error, whether I just want to print or divide

I tryed every solution that chatgpt proposed me including the pandas package, the index solution and some others but every time it is a tuple problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the first element in the tuple is a dataframe, so:

```py
df = test[0]
df["Result"] = df["Price Close"] / df["Dividend Per Share - Mean"]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Instrument  Dividend Per Share - Mean  Price Close      Result
0        IBM                    6.67500       140.88   21.105618
1     AAPL.O                    0.97507       132.23  135.610777
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed, I'm only starting with programming so I get stuck on stupid things like this, If you have some time, could you detail what you did because I really struggle at understanding the tuple system

Comment: @HugoMISZCZAK I'd start at *what is tuple* question. Python has [good documentation about the tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) you could check.